# Sending video to Android Camera

Tags: applications, camera

I'm testing an app that will require users to verify their identity with front facing id, back facing id and a selfie. It's really tedious to do the tests by hand one by one, i'd like to have a few people make videos in different lighting conditions, then I can send those videos to the camera feed of a real android phone and see how the app fares.

I know it's possible to do something like this on PC with ManyCam, where you can send a video to the camera api, I was wondering if there's a similar app or method to achieve the same thing on androids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing, depending on your app you have a few choices:

If the the app just needs camera and is configurable either:

a) use the Android emulator on PC which [can take a USB webcam as input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792615/295004) and use that to inject the images/video feed.

b) Android devices starting with Android 9 can [accept external USB Camera](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) [and use the standard API or need custom libraries for earlier version of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895097/295004). This would require the app to support such alternate inputs.

If you are testing biometric, [there is a way to test with fingerprint using emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35335892/295004) but on physical hardware [per the documentation](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/face-authentication) `secure camera hardware is required to prevent injection attacks on face authentication.`

Comment: I'm about to deepdive, thank you for the neat answer! I'll report back with my findings.